# How to change html using React event listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was trying to make a select appear whenever the value of the variable isDisabled is set to false, however no change to the html is made, I have tried to change the html dynamically in several ways this was the last and least messy attempt, but no it worked anyway. What I expect is that whenever I select some type of person (PF or PJ) the respective select box appears.

```js
export default function App() {
  let isDisabled = true;
  let isDisabledPF = true;
  function showOptions(value) {
    if (value === 'PF') {
      isDisabled = false;
      isDisabledPF = false;
    } else if (value === 'PJ') {
      isDisabled = false;
      isDisabledPF = true;
    } else {
      isDisabled = true;
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form action="">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h4>Selecione a opção que melhor te define:</h4>
            <div>
              <select defaultValue={null}
                onChange={(e) => { showOptions(e.target.value) }}>
                <option value="none"></option>
                <option value="PF">Pessoa Física</option>
                <option value="PJ">Pessoa Jurídica</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          {(isDisabled) ? <></> : (isDisabledPF) ? (
            <>
              <select>
                <option value="none"></option>
                <option value="fotografo">Fotógrafo</option>
              </select>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <select>
                <option value="none"></option>
                <option value="turismo">Agência de Turismo</option>
              </select>
            </>
          )}
          <button type='submit'>
            Enviar
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is a critical and fundamental concept in React... *state*.

Don't use a normal variable, use a state value:

```
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);
const [isDisabledPF, setIsDisabledPF] = useState(true);
```

Then you can update state in your function by calling the `set*` functions above, for example:

```
if (value === 'PF') {
  setIsDisabled(false);
  setIsDisabledPF(false);
}
// etc.
```

Updating state will trigger the component to re-render, and the new render will have the new state values to produce the updated result.

Otherwise, while your current code *does* successfully update the values of your variables, what it *doesn't do* is trigger React to re-render anything.

Comment: I thought the same thing happened with normal variables, that's why I had even forgotten about states. It worked, but i can only marked as answered after 6 minutes. Thank you.